# Managed Bean losing import statements

Tags: java, xpages

I created a New Java Class bean but when I try to add import statements they disappear when I save it.  Other code save but it doesn't keep code such as

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.openntf.xsp.debugtoolbar.beans.DebugToolbarBean;
import com.ibm.commons.util.StringUtil;
import lotus.domino.Database;
```

I am unable to figure out how to stop this behavior.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the imports in the class?  If not, you might have your IDE configured to "clean up" unused imports when saving.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if I use the import statement then it is saved.  If I don't use it it disappears ie

```
package com.cascorp;
import java.io.Serializable;
import lotus.domino.Database;
public class getFAQdata implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
Database nabDb = session.getDatabase(session.getServerName(), nabDbname, false);
}
```

The statement import lotus.domino.Database; doesn't disappears. I never noticed this behavoir before.

Comment: That is a very common feature in any decent IDE. And a useful one: you don't want unused imports in your source code. And of course, you want properly indented source code. And you want class names that follow java naming conventions.